# Passing reference as lvalue/rvalue depending on function signature

Tags: c++, c++11, move

Let's say I have some data :

```
struct Bar {};
```

I need to wrap a function and feed it with this data.

```
template<typename F>
void foo(F f) {
    Bar bar;
    f(bar);
}
```

As you can see in this trivial example:

- `bar` is not a temporary
- I don't need it after calling `f`

I want to support multiple function signatures, such as :

```
foo([](Bar){}); // (1)
foo([](Bar&){}); // (2)
foo([](Bar&&){}); // (3)
```

However gcc complains :

```
f(bar); // (3) : cannot bind 'Bar' lvalue to 'Bar&&'
f(std::move(bar)); // (2) : no match for call to ...
```

How would you do to get both ?

Comment: Have you provided Bar(Bar&& ) constructor?

Comment: Actually, the structure is move/copy constructible/assignable

Answer (score 1):

```
struct BarIsh{
  Bar&b;
  operator Bar&&()&&{return std::move(b);}
  operator Bar&()&&{return b;}
};
```

then `f(BarIsh{bar})`.

The downside is that if `f` takes a deduced parameter, it gets a `BarIsh` not a `Bar`.

Assuming you have a SFINAE friendly `result_of`...

```
template<class...>struct voider{using type=void;};
template<class...Ts>using void_t=typename voider<Ts...>::type;

template<class...>struct types{using type=types;};

namespace details{
  template<template<class...>class Z,class types,class=void>
  struct can_apply:std::false_type{};
  template<template<class...>class Z,class...Ts>
  struct can_apply<Z,types<Ts...>,void_t<Z<Ts...>>>:
    std::true_type
  {};
};
template<template<class...>class Z,class...Ts>
using can_apply=details::can_apply<Z,types<Ts...>>;

template<class Sig>
using result_of_t=typename std::result_of<Sig>::type;

template<class Sig>
using can_invoke=can_apply<result_of_t,Sig>;
```

and now we can test.

```
template<typename F>
void foo(F&& f,std::true_type)
{
  Bar bar;
  std::forward<F>(f)(std::move(bar));
}

template<typename F>
void foo(F&& f,std::false_type)
{
  Bar bar;
  std::forward<F>(f)(bar);
}


template<typename F>
void foo(F f)
{
  foo(std::forward<F>(f),can_apply<F(Bar&&)>{});
}
```

and done.  (there may be typos above, code written on phone)

Comment: Interesting, however it seems a bit too much to me. For now, I force the use of move semantics (using a lambda adapter if necessary) and it sounds like a good compromise regarding maintenance.